# Which Zelda game do these screenshots belong to?

Tags: game-identification, legend-of-zelda-series

I was watching a Youtube [video](https://youtu.be/AzRIGdGZgKU?t=15m2s) on all Zelda intros, but I couldn't identify one gameplay video. I am attaching some screenshots from the video.

Which Zelda game do these screenshots belong to?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am confused as to what relevance your "chronological order" has to your question... did you really need to include that?

Comment: It was to indicate the gradual visual improvements. Something that I was thingking about, but yes, the question can start without it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These images are from [Hyrule Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyrule_Warriors).

Comment: This is the Zelda flavored version of Dynasty Warriors in case you were wondering why we have a Zelda game without the word 'Zelda'.

Comment: Being a huge fan of the Dynasty Warriors and Samurai warriors series (as well as Zelda series) I was planning to check this out... but I just loaded up an actual gameplay video and the character animations are exactly the same ones as in Samurai Warriors... I think I won't be able to take this seriously. :/

Comment: @Nelson Does Hyrule Warriors contribute to the story line of The Legend of Zelda Series?

Comment: @iamcreasy No, the story is either (a) non-canon, or (b) on a new, separate  timeline distinct from all the other Zelda games; depending on who you ask.